# Kafka Streams multiple objects in a topic and deserizalization

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams

In my kafka streams application, I use one topic for multiple object types, seriazliazed as JSON. I use class name as a key and my idea was that consumers will filter only a subset of incoming entries by key and deserialize them from JSON. I assumed that I can apply initial filtering without defining serdes, but in such case source stream is inferred to `<Object,Object>` and the following code does not compile:

```
 return streamsBuilder.stream("topic")
            .filter((k, v) -> k.equals("TestClassA"))
            .groupByKey()
            .reduce((oldValue, newValue) -> newValue,
                    Materialized.<String, TestClassA, KeyValueStore<Bytes, byte[]>>as(StoreManager.STORE_NAME)
                    .withKeySerde(Serdes.String())
                    .withValueSerde(new JsonSerde<>(TestClassA.class)));
```

It compiles if I add types to stream definition:

```
return streamsBuilder.stream(businessEntityTopicName, Consumed.with(Serdes.String(), new JsonSerde<>(TestClassA.class))) {...}
```

But in this case I get runtime exceptions when for example object of TestClassB appears in a topic. 
What is the best practice for such cases or should I just use different topics for different objects?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you don't specify any `Serde` in `#stream()` and don't overwrite the default from `StreamsConfig` Kafka Streams will use byte-array serdes. Thus, you would get

```java
KStream<byte[], byte[]> streams = builder.<byte[], byte[]>stream("topicName");
```

> Note, that Java itself falls back to `KStream<Object, Object>` if you don't specify the correct type on the right hand side as shown above. But the actual type at runtime would be `byte[]` for both cases.

Thus, you could apply a filter, but it would need to work on `byte[]` data type.

I guess, what you actually want to do is to only specify a `StringSerde` for the key:

```
KStream<String, byte[]> streams = builder.<String, byte[]>("topicName", Consumed.with(Serdes.String(), null)); // null with fall back to defaul Serde from StreamConfig
```

This allows you to apply your `filter()` based on `String` keys before the `groupByKey()` operation.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I'm using JsonSerde from spring-kafka that is indeed working with byte arrays. This serde needs to explicitly declare a type. If I specify the source stream as `<String,byte[]>` , compiler complains about types in reduce operation - since I need to end up with objects of TestClassA in my KTable, I specify it in Materialized<...> and in my Serde, but it expects a `byte[]`. Should I also apply some kind of map() operation? I would appreciate if you provide a code snippet or some link where different json object types are consumed from one topic.

Comment: I see. Input value type is `byte[]` and `reduce()` does not allow to change the value type -- you can use `aggregate()` instead to change the output type.

Answer (score 0):

I have a similar use case. I make all the possible objects inherit a common interface (Event) and annotate with @JsonTypeInfo so jackson can deserialize the object properly.

```
streamsBuilder.stream("topic")//need to add some sort of JSONSerde<Event> to this stream call, i use personally use the one bundled with spring
            .filter((k, v) -> v instanceOf testClassA)
```